# How to replace plyr::ddply with data.table

Tags: r, data.table, geospatial, plyr, r-sf

I have an aggregation operation that counts points in polygons in R that currently uses `plyr::ddply()` as the main function, where I need to group by 2 variables: `dayofweek` and `hour`. It is quite slow, so I'd like to replace it with a faster function, like something from the `data.table` package.

### Reprex

#### Create the data frames

The main goal of the operation is to take a data frame of points  `df`, and use the `st_intersects()` method from the `sf` package to count how many points intersect the polygons in `grid.sf`.

Create DF object

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(plyr)

df <- data.frame(X = seq(1,100,1), 
                 dayofweek = rep(c("Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thur"), 20),
                 hour = sample(seq(0, 23, 1),  100, replace = T),
                 lat = sample(seq(37.1234, 37.2345, 0.001),  100, replace = T),
                 lon = sample(seq(-122.5432, -122.4111, 0.001),  100, replace = T)
)


projcrs <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"

df <- st_as_sf(x = df,                         
               coords = c("lon", "lat"),
               crs = projcrs)
```

Create grid.sf object

```
# Function to create the grid we need
buildBaseGrid <- function(x) {
  
  # create a 500m tesseract over these points
  g <- st_make_grid(x, cellsize = 0.005)
  
  # plot to make sure
  # ggplot() +
  #   geom_sf(data = df.sf, size = 3) +
  #   geom_sf(data = g, alpha = 0)
  # 
  # ggplot() +
  #   geom_sf(data = g, alpha = 0)
  grid.sf <- st_sf(g) 
  # Need to expand by day of week
  days <- c('SU', 'MO', 'TU', 'WE', 'TH', 'FR', 'SA')
  hours <- c('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12',
             '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23')
  grid.sf <- expand.grid(g, days, hours)
  grid.sf$id <- 1:nrow(grid.sf)
  
  #### Clean up home grid
  
  # Calc centroid
  grid.sf <- grid.sf %>%
    dplyr::mutate(center = sf::st_centroid(grid.sf$Var1))
  
  # Parse out lat and lon
  grid.sf <- grid.sf %>%
    dplyr::mutate(lonn = sf::st_coordinates(grid.sf$center)[,1]) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(latt = sf::st_coordinates(grid.sf$center)[,2])
  
  # Create primary key field
  grid.sf <- grid.sf %>%
    dplyr::mutate(pkey = paste0(lonn,";",latt,";",Var2,";",Var3))
  
  
  grid.sf <- st_as_sf(grid.sf) 
  
  return(grid.sf)
  
  
}

# Now build the grid.sf object
grid.sf <- buildBaseGrid(df)
```

#### Current operation with plyr::ddply

```
# Create function to use in operation
myf <- function(x) {
  x <- as.data.frame(x)
  df <- df %>% dplyr::filter(dayofweek %in% x$Var2)
  df <- df %>% dplyr::filter(hour %in% x$Var3)
  x$count <- sf::st_intersects(x$Var1, df) %>% lengths()
  x %>%
    data.frame(x)
}

# Do the operation
output <-  plyr::ddply(grid.sf, .(Var2, Var3), .fun = myf, .parallel = F) %>% as.data.frame()
```

This takes about 4 seconds on my machine, but I have to do this process hundreds of times so it really adds up.

I've tried to start with data.table but find the translation difficult. This is the only (non-functioning) code I have for this `data.table()` attempt:

```
test4 <- grid.sf[, .(test = myf()), by = key(grid.sf)]
```

So, if there is a way to translate this `ddply` to a `data.table` operation, I would be tickled pink, as `data.table` is much faster.

Thanks!

Comment: what is `g` in your Create grid.sf object? you can prob do something like `grid.sf[df, on=c("Var2"="dayofweek", "Var3"="hour"), count := length(st_intersects(Var1, df))]` and if you have to run it many times,  it would be good to add an iteration id to grid.sf so that you can churn through the whole dataset in 1 go

Comment: @chinsoon12 'g' is just the grid object that I am converting to a simple feature in the next line

Comment: sorry missed out the scroll bar on the right. assuming your day of the week is labeled consistently, this should get you started: `library(data.table);
setDT(grid.sf);
setDT(df);
grid.sf[, Var2 := as.character(Var2)];
grid.sf[, Var3 := as.numeric(Var3)];

grid.sf[df, on=c("Var2"="dayofweek", "Var3"="hour"), count := lengths(st_intersects(Var1, i.geometry))]`

Comment: @chinsoon12 I get an error when I run the above snippet

Comment: What is the error msg